# Compare 2 consecutive rows of a column in PBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I would like to compare 2 consecutive rows of the same column ("Niveau num") of a table in PBI and display the result of this comparison in another column ("Niveau arbre"). This can be done very easily in Excel but Power BI is online and it is more complicated to set it up.

I added an index column to have access to the row number and I wrote the following formula in Power Query:

**= Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes permutées", "Niveau arbre", each if Estimations[Niveau num]{[Index]} > Estimations[Niveau num]{[Index]+1} then 1 else 0, type number)**

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm95J.png)

I then get the error:

**Expression.Error : A cyclic reference was detected during the evaluation.**

Here is all the code:

```
let
    Source = Access.Database(File.Contents("C:\Users\T0275244\Desktop\BDD Access PBI\Off\BDD-Off.accdb"), [CreateNavigationProperties=true]),
    _Estimations = Source{[Schema="",Item="Estimations"]}[Data],
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée" = Table.AddColumn(_Estimations, "Niveau num", each List.Sum(List.Transform(Text.ToList([WBS]), each if _ = "." then 0 else 1))),
    #"Lignes filtrées" = Table.SelectRows(#"Personnalisée ajoutée", each [WBS] <> null and [WBS] <> ""),
    #"Type modifié" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Lignes filtrées",{{"Niveau num", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Index ajouté" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Type modifié", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Colonnes permutées" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Index ajouté",{"Devis", "WBS", "Désignation", "Qté", "Respde Lot niveau2", "Centre de taux", "Activity", "Activities", "ECPS/Transverse", "SW Comp", "MO ING", "MO TECH", "Total MO (H)", "Total MO (K€)", "Autres MO", "Total MO et Autre MO", "Total tarifs (PRV)", "Divers CPP", "Total MO et Div Tarifs", "Durée ID Ingé", "Nb de Voyages", "Divers transports", "Total Frais Déplacement", "INTRAGROUP PURCHASES", "EXTERNAL PURCHASES", "Total DEVIS (non inflaté)", "Commentaires", "Options", "Devis(Devis)", "Index", "Niveau num"}),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes permutées", "Niveau arbre", each if Estimations[Niveau num]{[Index]} > Estimations[Niveau num]{[Index]+1} then 1 else 0, type number)
in
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée1"
```

Would you have an idea to solve this?

Thanks in advance for your help

[image]

Comment: You need to share the rest of your code. You are referring to another step out of order somewhere but have not provided enough detail to determine where

Comment: That is the only code I have for this column, I updated the post with a screenshot. What do you think I can add to help?

Comment: Go into home .. advanced editor .. copy all of your code and paste it into your question

Comment: I just did it, thank you angain, let me know if it's more clear now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

#"Personnalisée ajoutée1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes permutées", "Niveau arbre", each if Estimations[Niveau num]{[Index]} > Estimations[Niveau num]{[Index]+1} then 1 else 0, type number)

to

#"Personnalisée ajoutée1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes permutées", "Niveau arbre", each if [Niveau num]{[Index]} > [Niveau num]{[Index]+1} then 1 else 0, type number)

you cannot refer to Estimations  which is (a) the wrong name, since you used _Estimations, and (b) wrong since that step would not have the index added yet anyway

**EDIT** -- from your updated image, your column is not numerical so you can't use >.  Change the column format to numerical before the last Table.AddColumn()

**FINAL EDIT**

[image]

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each try if  #"Added Index"{[Index]}[Column1] > #"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[Column1] then 1 else 0 otherwise 0)
in  #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Now I have the error: 
`
Expression.Error : Sorry... We could not convert the value 1 to List type.
Details:
    Value=1
    Type=[Type]
`
Where 1 is the value I have in the current line of Niveau num...

Do you have an idea how to solve that? @horseyride

Comment: What row is generating the error in you code when you click on each step one at a time

Comment: I am sorry about that but can you tell me where I can find this mode? @horseyride

Comment: , each try if [Niveau num]{[Index]} > [Niveau num]{[Index]+1} then 1 else 0 otherwise 0, type number)

Comment: If you want further assistance you need to post what your source dat looks like.  At this point Im just guessing and it would be frankly easier to write something from scratch

Comment: I just updated the post explaining from the begining what I need to code, is it more helpful? Thank you again for your time and your help @horseyride

Comment: you code is not working because somewhere in that [Niveau num] column is text or an error, not a number. You can use the code I pasted above in my comments to get around this

Comment: Thank you! Now I don't have errors anymore but the column is full of 0...

Comment: From your image, [Niveau num] is formatted as ABC123, which means the column is not numbers. So you can't compare the contents using > or other numerical operations. 
To fix that, before your Table.AddColumn(), transform the [Niveau num] column to type number.  Also, please stop changing your question text. You can edit it to add more information.  Without the original question my answer now makes no sense

Comment: I changed that but still have the same problem with the column full of 0... 
Yes, sorry about that I will add informations next time, not not familiar with this yet, sorry again

Comment: Sorry, I give up at this point. Perhaps someone else can help.  I changed my answer to include a generic example if that helps