# How to compare 2 cells in PBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I would like to compare 2 cells in PBI that are in 2 consecutives rows of a same column like here:

[image: Model]

The first one is used to have the index of the row, the second one is the one I want that contains the rows I want to compare and the last one is where I put the result of the compare formula.

To create the last one I use this power query formula:

```
try if [Niveau num]{[Index]} > [Niveau num]{[Index]+1} then 1 else 0 otherwise -1
```

But as you can see, it return me a column full of -1, meaning that the try always failed...

If we use an if instead of a try, this is the error we get:

```
Expression.Error : Sorry... We could not convert the value 4 to List type.
Details:
    Value=4
    Type=[Type]
```

where 4 is the value in the curent line of the column I'm trying to compare

Do you have an idea how to fix that?

--- Here is the full code:

```
let
    Source = Access.Database(File.Contents("C:\Users\T0275244\Desktop\BDD Access PBI\Off\BDD-Off.accdb"), [CreateNavigationProperties=true]),
    _Estimations = Source{[Schema="",Item="Estimations"]}[Data],
    #"Lignes filtrées" = Table.SelectRows(_Estimations, each ([WBS] <> null)),
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée" = Table.AddColumn(#"Lignes filtrées", "Niveau num", each List.Sum(List.Transform(Text.ToList([WBS]), each if _ = "." then 0 else 1))),
    #"Type modifié" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Personnalisée ajoutée",{{"Niveau num", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Index ajouté" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Type modifié", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
   #"Personnalisée ajoutée1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Index ajouté", "Niveau arbre", each try if #"Index ajouté"{[Index]}[Niveau num] > #"Index ajouté"{[Index]+1}[Niveau num] then 1 else 0 otherwise -1)
in
    #"Personnalisée ajoutée1"
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You were already shown how by horseyride on your previous question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare 2 consecutive rows of a column in PBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75481697/compare-2-consecutive-rows-of-a-column-in-pbi)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem

Comment: You literally just need to follow the guidance given. Your code for your added column is not referring to a table as shown in @horseyride's solution so that is why you're getting -1 everywhere. This is the same question with the same solution.

Comment: If I replace with reference to the table like that: try if Estimations[Niveau num]{Estimations[Index]} > Estimations[Niveau num]{Estimations[Index]+1} then 1 else 0 otherwise -1  the probleme is still the same

Comment: Paste your full code from the advanced editor and mark your previous question as solved and I will take a look.

Comment: I just edited my post with the full code, thank you for your help!

Comment: I'll add an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you expect?

[image]

```
try if [Niveau num] > #"Index ajouté"{[Index]}[Niveau num] then 1 else 0 otherwise -1
```

[image]

Comment: Your patience exceeds mine by a fair bit

Comment: I actually thought yours exceeeded my own lol

Comment: Thanks for your help, after working on it, this answer was the right one for my use case:
each try if #"Index ajouté"{[Index]}[Niveau num] < #"Index ajouté"{[Index]+1}[Niveau num] then 0 else 1 otherwise -1
But when I execute it, it looks like it is creating rows to infinite and now I am trying to find out why and stop it

Comment: You have literally been shown why twice. I'm not sure there is anything else we can do.